# Web Application Publish Profile: disable connection strings autogeneration

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, publish, publish-profiles

Is there a way to disable connection strings auto generation in publish profile?
I would like to generate package and SetParameters file with parameters specified in Parameters.xml only, without any connection strings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865379/removing-connectionstring-when-deploying-with-visual-studio-2012 can be helpful to you. Have a look at that Thread.

Comment: AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings doesn't work for me. I added it to proj file, but Publish command still creates connection string parameters in Publish profile.

Comment: I think you also need to add this to your web.config transformation `<connectionStrings>
      <add xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Answer (score 1):

AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings with `<UpdateDestWebConfig>False</UpdateDestWebConfig>` actually works. Thanks.