# Web Deploy Adds Extra Connection Strings (Adds the Same Connection Twice)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, webdeploy

First off to get the research out of the way. I have already seen and applied the solution in the answer to this question here: [Web Deploy / Publish is adding a unknown connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966449/web-deploy-publish-is-adding-a-unknown-connection-string)

It does not work, and by that I mean, it does not have any affect whatsoever on the problem I'm facing.

Another piece of information that might help is that I am working on Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

Alright, now the problem that I am facing is a strange one. I have two DB connections in my `web.config` file. They are defined like this:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Test.mdf;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ErpConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Test.mdf;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The context associated with `DefaultConnection` is `ApplicationDbContext`. And the context associated with `ErpConnection` is `ErpEntityContext`. Each of these is defined like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class ErpEntityContext : DbContext
{
    public ErpEntityContext()
        : base("ErpConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

However, web deploy decides that `ApplicationDbContext` and `DefaultConnection` must be two very different things so ends up showing them as two different connections like in the image below:

[image]

Removing `DefaultConnection` from `web.config` gets rid of the double entry (this is obviously not the solution since I would like to have my connection string around). Changing the name of the connection string does not matter at all. It also does not happen with `ErpConnection`.

This happened from one session of Visual Studio to another and appeared out of nowhere yesterday. Then after some hours it automatically disappeared when I relaunched VS. I thought it was fixed and everything was dandy but today it has reappeared. I am completely lost as to what may be going wrong here. As much as I am interested in a solution, I would also appreciate if someone could tell me why this is happening.

**EDIT:**

To clarify and answer the questions asked in the comments, I do not have any transformations specified and the problem appears in all build configurations.

Also, I have tried to publish with `Remove additional files at destination` checked and unchecked. Similarly, I have tried to publish with `Exclude files from the App_Data folder` checked and unchecked to see if I can fool the thing ( :) ). But to no avail so far.

**UPDATE:**

Further investigation of the issue reveals that the culprit may be the use of `Loaded` event in `DbConfiguration`:

```
Loaded += (sender, args) => args.ReplaceService<DbProviderServices>((s, _) => new CachingProviderServices(s, transactionHelper, new ExampleCachingPolicy()));
```

The documentation for this event says:

> Occurs during EF initialization after the DbConfiguration has been
>   constructed but just before it is locked ready for use. Use this event
>   to inspect and/or override services that have been registered before
>   the configuration is locked. Note that this event should be used
>   carefully since it may prevent tooling from discovering the same
>   configuration that is used at runtime.

The question is what the fix would be in case this event needs to be used. I will write an answer if I find one but if anyone else knows please feel free to do so.

Comment: Is it your intention that both connection strings are identical? Also, do you have any transformations specified (can you expand your .config file and see sub-nodes)? Finally, does the problem apply in all build configurations, just debug, etc?

Comment: @Basic Yes, that is correct. However, changing those strings to something different has the same result. One connection gets displayed twice and messes stuff up on publish.

Comment: @Basic thanks for the questions, I updated the question to clarify the situation. But in short, no transformations, and yes it happens in all cases.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution ?

Comment: @Alexandre Never was able to figure it out. Gave us on it.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo Thanks! I've been working around it without any real problems but I was curious.

Answer (score 1):

After long hours of research and experimentation, I finally found a way to get rid of the double entry: give your connectionString the same name as your Context!

So, to answer the question, renaming the connection string `DefaultConnection` to `ApplicationDbContext` should remove the double entry. Note that you'll also need to update the following with the new connection string name:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("name=ApplicationDbContext")
```

Sadly enough though, I decided to leave it as it was (with the double entry) since it gives me the possibility to either use `Execute Code First migrations (runs on application start)` or `Update database` to update the database.

The advantage of using `Update database` is that you can run custom SQL scripts before and after the Schema update.

Comment: Wen you changed the name, did you also changed it in this line ```public ApplicationDbContext(): base("name=DefaultConnection")```? As far as I know, migrations will use the parameterless constructor.

Comment: Yes I did. Although our code uses an appSetting that defines the connection string name to use so I only had to update the proper appSetting. I haven't tested it thoroughly but the app seemed to be working normally.

Comment: I had some issues with one of my projects. Depending on how your app starts it may read the configuration from a different file. For example, an EF project in a solution with a MVC project set up as "StartUp Project", will read the appSetting from Web.config instead of app.config.

Comment: Thanks! I do not have the project to test this on anymore. If someone can confirm that this works then I'll accept this answer.